# Try to Match string with multiple pattern in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am trying the below python code and getting an error. What I want is if target_branch matches any pattern in testrel variable then it should say yes. It is possible that the value of target_branch could be in the format release/1.0.0 or r11_i12 so if it matches to any pattern then say yes otherwise nothing. Is it possible to define multiple patterns like the following way?

```
import re

testrel = ['r(\d+)_(i\d+)', 'release/\d+.\d+.\d+']
target_branch = "r11_i12"

if re.match(testrel, target_branch):
    print 'Yes'
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    if re.match(testrel, target_branch):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\re.py", line 229, in _compile
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Are you testing 1 string or 2 strings? What does `target_branch` look like?

Comment: @Thefourthbird
 target_branch variable value could be sometime release/4.8.0 or r11_i13

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
import re

testrel = r'^r[\w+\/.]*'
target_branch = ["r11_i12",
    "release/1.0.0",
"release/4.8.0",
"r11_i13",]

for x in target_branch:
    if re.match(testrel, x):
        print('Yes', end = '; ')

# Output:
## Yes; Yes; Yes; Yes;
```

Caution:  this is a narrow answer to your requirement.  if you want to be more specific, consider alternate pattern to avoid unnecessary matches.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) is a pattern and you are trying to pass a list.

You could use a single regex using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) matching either the one or the other.

```
(?:r\d+_i\d+|release/\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$
```

re.match starts the match at the beginning of the string so you don't need the `^` anchor, but you could add an anchor `$` to assert the end of the string so that for example `release/4.8.0 text` is not a match.

Note to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LHVAMg/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/g38Mt2)

For example:

```
import re

testrel = r"(?:r\d+_i\d+|release/\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$"
target_branches = ["r11_i12", "release/4.8.0"]

for target_branch in target_branches:
    if re.match(testrel, target_branch): 
        print 'Yes'
```